# Where libraries are stored for AWS Lambda Functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm a newbie in AWS Lambda functions. I used a script in AWS CLI in order to create an aws function in Node.js. This script has a config file called config.json. After function creation, I'm able to see the code on Lambda AWS Console and here comes my doubt. The code has this line:
var config = require('./config.json');
So, where this "./config.json" file is actually stored. Could I be able to edit the contents of config.json after deployment of lambda function?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your files are placed into the directory specified in the environment variable `LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT`. You can read this via nodejs as `process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT`.

The code you deploy, including the `config.json` file are read-only, but if you do wish to modify files on the server, you may do so underneath `/tmp`. Mind, those changes will only be valid for that single container, for its lifecycle (4m30s - 4hrs). Lambda will auto-scale up and down between 0 and 100 containers, by default.

Global variables are also retained across invocations, so if you read `config.json` into a global variable, then modify that variable, those changes will persist throughout the lifecycle of the underlying container(s). This can be useful for caching information across invocations, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

> So, where this `./config.json` file is actually stored?

It should be stored in the same directory as your Lambda handler function. They should be bundled in a zip file and deployed to AWS. If you didn't deploy it that way then that file doesn't currently exist.

If your Lambda function consists of multiple files you will have to bundle your files and [deploy it to AWS as a zip file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html).

You cannot edit the source of external libraries/files via the AWS Lambda web console. You can only edit the source of the Lambda function handler via the web console.

Comment: So, in this case I should edit config.json locally and then redeploy that function. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, if you deploy the function as a zipped deployment package that includes the `config.json` file.